# Why do user and system cpu in cpuacct.stat not add up to cpuacct.usage?

Tags: cpu-usage, cgroup

Question relates to Linux cgroups cpu accounting.

I noticed this at the container level, but it persists up to top level.  For instance:

```
# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.stat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.usage
user 34618
system 18038
743932863030
```

The units for the former are 100ths of a second and for the latter nanoseconds, i.e. 346.18, 180.38 and 743.932863030

My question is: why do the first two not add up to the latter?

You might think "ah, they start from a different origin", so here are the same metrics a few minutes later:

```
# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.stat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.usage
user 40028
system 22098
818501029494
```

The deltas are 54.1, 40.6 and 74.57.

Comment: Maybe this disclaimer at the end of the respective Linux [kernel docs section](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cpuacct.txt) is helpful: `It is possible to see slightly outdated values for user and system times due to the batch processing nature of percpu_counter`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, it just seems the differences I'm seeing are much larger than I'd expect from "slightly outdated values"

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a kernel developer, but, digging through the kernel source code, cpuacct.usage (updated via [cgroup_account_cputime](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/cgroup.h#L772)) and cpuacct.stat (updated via [cgroup_account_cputime_field](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/cgroup.h#L786) seem to be calculated by different kernel components.

From what I understand the output of cpu.stat seems to heavily depend on kernel configuration, in particular [CONFIG_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_GEN.html), [CONFIG_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_NATIVE](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING_NATIVE.html) and [CONFIG_VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/VIRT_CPU_ACCOUNTING.html). From their descriptions they seem to be more precise. A relevant file is [kernel/sched/cputime.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/cputime.c), where timing updates seems to be caused by some kernel events(irqs etc.)

The output of cpuacct.usage seems to be calculated by the scheduler when switching between tasks. For example [update_curr](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L834), which calls cgroup_account_cputime is called from [enqueue_entity](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sched/fair.c#L3963) and dequeue_entity which seem to schedule tasks. This does not seem as affected by configuration.

Answer (score 2):

`cpuacct.stat` contains CPU usage accumulated by process(es) in the cgroup expressed in ticks of 1/100th of a second, also called "user jiffies" (`USER_HZ`). It may not be as precise as the CPU times accounted in nanoseconds.

You can obtain the `USER_HZ` from shell (typically `100`)

```
$ getconf CLK_TCK
100
```

This should be mapped to a number of scheduler ticks per second, unless you are on a real-time or [tickless kernel](https://lwn.net/Articles/549580/).

`cpuacct.usage` gives the overall CPU time in nanoseconds, measured as precisely as the kernel can report usage times.

`cpuacct.usage_all` or `cpuacct.usage_percpu` will report usage per CPU core (thread) again measured in nanoseconds.

Note that the `cpuacct` subsystem was originally [written as a demonstration of cgroups capabilities](https://lwn.net/Articles/606004/). It wasn't meant for precise reporting.